# Right Alignment of numerical value in PDF using Apache PDFBox library

Tags: java, apache, pdf, spring-boot, pdfbox

My Spring boot Java application is using apache pdf box library {version 2.0.6} for generating pdf. I want decimal values to be right aligned. It means all decimal dot should align in same vertical line. I also attached screenShot.

```
    stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(xCordinate, yCordinate);
            stream.showText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
            List<String> resultList = processTextData(TextUtil.isEmpty(item.getDescription()) ? "-" : item.getDescription());
            int y = 0;
            int x = 50;
            int tempYcordinate = yCordinate;
            for (String string : resultList) {
                stream.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
                stream.showText(processStringForPdf(string));
                x = 0;
                y = -8;

            }
            tempYcordinate = tempYcordinate - (8 * resultList.size());
            stream.endText();
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(285, yCordinate);
            stream.showText("$" + NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(Util.round(item.getUnitPrice())));
            stream.newLineAtOffset(65, 0);
            stream.showText("$" + NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(Util.round(item.getExtPrice())));
            stream.endText();
            yCordinate = tempYcordinate;
```

[image: ScreenShot of the PDF]

Comment: What have you tried, what stopped you? Pdfbox as is does not even contain choose to automatically layout tables like in your screenshot, so you must have done some layout'ing and so know how to do that. Or do you use an add-on you don't mention?

Comment: Alignment depends on neighbouring property{column, here unit price and 
 ext price}.So I want to handle that also. if one quantity is 4 digit before the decimal point and another one 3 digit before the decimal point. The Alignment gets broken. Am not using any add-on

Comment: Have you heard of `PDFont.getStringWidth()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To right align the text you need to compute the width of the text to show and align the output position to

> (right alignment position) - (text width)

Find below a small snippet which shows the principle. You need to amend the snippet for your needs.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class RightAlignDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("out.pdf");
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

        PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        int fontSize = 12;

        stream.setFont(font, fontSize);

        double[] values = {0, 0.1, 0.01, 12.12, 123.12, 1234.12, 123456.12};

        int columnOneLeftX = 50;
        int columnTwoRightX = 170;
        int columnThreeOffsetX = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(columnOneLeftX, 700 - (i*10));
            // show some left aligned non fixed width text
            stream.showText("value " + values[i]);

            // format the double value with thousands separator and 
            // two decimals
            String text = String.format("%,.2f", values[i]);
            // get the width of the formated value
            float textWidth = getTextWidth(font, fontSize, text);
            // align the position to (right alignment minus text width)
            stream.newLineAtOffset(columnTwoRightX - textWidth, 0);
            stream.showText(text);

            // align the positon back to columnTwoRightX plus offset for
            // column three
            stream.newLineAtOffset(textWidth + columnThreeOffsetX, 0);
            stream.showText("description " + i);
            stream.endText();
        }

        stream.close();
        doc.save(file);
        doc.close();
    }

    private static float getTextWidth(PDType1Font font, int fontSize, 
            String text) throws IOException {
        return (font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000.0f) * fontSize;
    }
}
```

PDF output

[image: snippet output]